# Можно ли реализовать передачу данных между пользователями без участия сервера на php

Tags: php

Можно ли реализовать передачу данных между пользователями без участия сервера на php?? Если нет, то какими языками можно это сделать. Если да, то как?

Comment: взаимодействие реализовать можно, посмотрите как это реализовано в хтмл 5.

Comment: Что за пользователи то? Юзеры сайта? Приложения? Игры?

Comment: Юзеры сайта-мессенджера, например

Comment: @ФилипповАртём, Вы что, не собираетесь хранить историю переписки пользователей? А как тогда Вы собираетесь отправлять её в ФСБ по запросу?

Comment: Неа, будет либо где-то в облаке скорее всего зашифрованное и у пользователя.

Comment: Судя по тому что удалось нарыть в интернете сейчас браузеры (и то не все) поддерживают открытые сокета на прослушивание (listen) только в рамках протокола WebRTC, по которому в принципе умудряются гонять произвольные данные.

Comment: Да, можно попробовать пиры